# Как проверить, что слово начинается с гласной (a, e, i, o, u)

Tags: python

Проверка с "а" получается, а как проверить остальные буквы?

```py
def begin_with_vowel(words: list):
     return [word for word in words if word[0] == "a"]

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    word_list = ["automobile","motorbike","Animal","cat","Dog","APPLE","orange"]
    for vowelled in begin_with_vowel(word_list):
        print(vowelled)
```

Comment: `word.startswith(("a", "e", ...))`

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 3):

Как ответил @Danis в комментариях, решение будет вот таким:

```py
def begin_with_vowel(words: list):
     return [word for word in words if word.startswith(("a", "e", "i", "o", "u"))]

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    word_list = ["automobile","motorbike","Animal","cat","Dog","APPLE","orange"]
    for vowelled in begin_with_vowel(word_list):
        print(vowelled)
```